# Print certain tabs

Tags: excel, printing

How do I print only certain tabs in an Excel file.

Comment: From Excel or from code?

Answer (score 2):

From the UI - go to the desired worksheet and go to File -> Print

From VBA -

```
Call Worksheets("MySheet").PrintOut
```

or

```
Call MySheet.PrintOut
```

or if you have a more than one

```
Dim shts As New Collection
Call shts.Add(Sheet1)
Call shts.Add(Sheet3)
Call shts.Add(Sheet5)

Dim sht As Worksheet: For Each sht In shts
    Call sht.PrintOut
Next sht
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the worksheet you want to print, select print and under print click 'active sheet'.

Full details here - [MS Office Help Page for Excel printing](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA010346461033.aspx).

Comment: 'Active sheet' is the default selection

Comment: You can also Ctrl-left-click or Shift-left-click on the tab names to group the sheets before printing

Answer (score 0):

It works as an array too:

Thisworkbook.Sheets(array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet5")).Printout

or:

Dim arString(1 to 3) as string

arString(1) = "Sheet1"
arString(2) = "Sheet3"
arString(3) = "Sheet5"

Thisworkbook.Sheets(arString).Printout

Either way would work.